# Cant install cordova in my mac os x

Tags: macos, cordova

When I am installing through terminal I got the error below

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/abp2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/abp2/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I followed many answers in this community, but still not able to install this.

According to some suggestion I have change install cordova code like that

```
$ sudo npm --proxy proxy-server:8080 install -g cordova
```

But here I am getting problem like that

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/plist/-/plist-1.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.47.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/plist/-/plist-1.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.47.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/plist/-/plist-1.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.47.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-1.0.2.tgz
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--proxy" "proxy-server:8080" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/abp2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: The problem is with your particular proxy. The issue is not that cordova n

Comment: try like this .npm --proxy http://proxy-server:8080/ install {your package-name} .

Comment: check your node version, I was having the same problem with node 0.10.32,updating to 0.10.33 fixed that

Comment: I have tried with the command   $ npm --proxy proxy-server:8080 install -g cordova  but there are also a lot error

Comment: Fabico I have installed v0.10.33 at the very beginning.

Comment: Are you actually using `--proxy proxy-server:8080` or are you replacing `proxy-server:8080` with your actual proxy server address?

Comment: Thanks Dawson Loudon. It works for me. But now after installing the cordova now I am getting the problem for creating a project Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)